# Laravel vive perdendo a sessão

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, session

Olá

Tenho um sistema desenvolvido em Laravel 5.6 que vive perdendo a sessão

Quando faço o login seto na sesão bem assim:

```
private $prefix = '';
public function __construct(){
    $this->prefix = env('APP_NAME')."_";
}

Session::put([
      $this->prefix.'login' =>  $login,
      $this->prefix.'id'    =>  $user->usua_id
   ]);
```

Este trecho `$this->prefix = env('APP_NAME')."_";` é para obter o nome do sistema. Por que?

Porque eu uso o mesmo sistema para visulizar em valores em simulação e para não dar conflito de sessão eu faço a concatenação com a variável de ambiente do `.env`, então tem direcionado para o banco de dados de produção e outro para ler dados em simulação

```
Em produção    

APP_NAME=SISTEMA

Em simulação

APP_NAME=SISTEMA_TEST
```

O sistema fica fazendo consulta a cada 3 segundos no banco de dados de dados  e parece que depois de algum tempo consultando (tipo 5 minutos, e eu programei para expirar a sessão em 24horas) ele simplesmente dá o erro 419

Até em paáginas em que não é preciso logar ele perde a sessão

Estou realizando a configuração do meu ajax assim:

```
      $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {'x-csrf-token': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')}
        })
        $.ajax({
            url: '{{ route('reader.readerList') }}',
            type: 'get',
            dataType: 'json',            
        }).done( data => {

       }
```

No meta da minha página template está assim:

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

Como posso resolver esse problema?

Comment: Verifique em config/session.php o 'lifetime' da sua sessão

Comment: Está setado para 1140, dois dias

Comment: Bem, a resposta é estranha, mas: defina  seu `session.php` para `database` ao invés de `file`

Comment: Não vou precisar configurar um banco de dados ?

Answer (score 0):

Isso estava acontecendo comigo quando eu colocava em algum link o comando Auth::logout(), exemplo:

```
<a href="{{ Auth::logout() }}">Sair</a>
```

Se isso estiver ocorrendo, o ideal seria remover esse comando de algum link da aplicação e colocá-lo dentro de alguma rota diretamente ou dentro de algum controller acessado por uma rota, exemplo:

```
<a href="{{ route('logout') }}">Sair</a>
```

Arquivo de rotas web.php:

```
Route::get('logout', function () { Auth::logout(); });
```